# php post adds forwardslash in the post variable of type string

Tags: java, php, android, http-post

I have problem in getting the exact value passed from android using post method to php.
I am passing this String from Android using http post :

```
String secret = "mtHa5YRivVrQ/ZNtoe2oxg==";
```

In the php I am getting this:

```
$secret = $_POST['secret'];

echo $secret
```

Output : `mtHa5YRivVrQ\/ZNtoe2oxg==`

You can see that in php it has added '\' after '/'. Why this is happening I don't understand. I want the exact string that I have passed from Android.

Comment: Its not same see the difference of slashes in the strings.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $secret = stripslashes($_POST['secret']);   
    }
```

or use PHP latest version....

Comment: I am using PHP 5.5.10 (cli) version. Let me try your answer

Comment: Anybody there to help?

Comment: Nobody there to help me out?